# Convert json to Class

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson, jackson-databind

I have a class with a data member defined with a @SerializedName annotation (see below).

```
public static final String SERIALIZED_NAME_ENGINE_ID = "engine_id";
  @SerializedName(SERIALIZED_NAME_ENGINE_ID)
  private String engineId;
```

I want to map JSON to the class.
I tried using the Jackson library,
but my code gives error saying "engine_id" not found.
It expects "engineId" in the JSON instead of "engine_id".

```
String json = "{\"engine_id\": \"Test\"}";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
CustomClass sample = mapper.readValue(fsjson
        CustomClass.class);`
```

Is there a way to map the SerializedName from the Json?
I am open to using GSON if it has the required capability.

Comment: Will you please add to your code example? I get the general idea, but I cannot copy/paste it and run it myself in its current state. Please add enough to your code so I can do that.

Comment: you need to post a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

### Long Answer

Read more about the Jackson library,
it provides most functionality you will ever need
(including the functionality that you have already identified).
Here is a [Baeldung Jackson Article](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson).

### Short Answer

Use the `@JsonProperty` annotation to identify the JSON field name.